# Trying to add multiple formulas in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm very new to Google Spreadsheets and I'm trying to add multiple formulas in one cell. This is my code so far, I'm not very good at formulas.

```
={SUBSTITUTE(C:C,"wd","Web Development"), SUBSTITUTE(C:C,"ch","Chores")}
```

This is one working equation if that helps:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C:C,"wd","Web Development")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Riley, using SUBSTITUTE, you "wrap" like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C:C,"wd","Web Development"),"ch","Chores"))
```

It's a bit like those Russian nesting dolls.

[image: Russian Nesting Dolls]

Comment: Instead of C:C use C3:C (3 is the row where the formula is added)

Comment: @Rubén, how do you know the OP's formula or data should start in Row 3? There is no mention of it in the post and no link to a sample spreadsheet. Am I missing something?

Comment: My previous comment was pointed to the OP, as they added a link to a spreadsheet into a comment to this answer but now the OP's comment is gone. (by bad not adding @reply to my previous comment, sorry)